# Extracting data-points from Graph from Web-page

Tags: python, html

I want to extract data-points from web-page with this [url](https://www.androidrank.org/application/whatsapp_messenger/com.whatsapp).

In this web-page there is graph of **Total Number of installs (*estimated)**
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtMWV.png)

I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920811) answer but couldn't figure it out.

I was trying to find requests and its responses as given in above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920811).

I tried to find that request whose response is data(like in the form of **JSON**) but couldn't find any such request.

I got following result :
[requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdZe8.jpg)

One requests is there which has response of **scripts** which makes graph but I am unable to find how it gets data : here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPeD0.jpg)

All the things which I have done with the help of above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920811) that I mentioned

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried and how it doesn't work ?

Comment: @WaLinke I have added what I have done